# Document-scope, Security scoped bookmarks for file packages

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to create document-scope security scoped bookmarks for file packages. That is, directories where `NSURLIsPackageKey` is `YES`. I know you're not normally supposed to be able to create document-scope bookmarks to directories, but I would have expected packages to be exempt from that (after all, I get access to them using an `NSOpenPanel` which isn't allowed to select directories, but there's no problem there).

I've got my entitlements set up with `com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.document-scope` = `true`, and I'm doing a basic bookmark creation call with a file URL that I've just received from an `NSOpenPanel` (so I have access):

```
NSError *bookmarkError = nil;
NSData *bookmark = [fileURL 
    bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
    includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
    relativeToURL:[self fileURL]
    error:&bookmarkError];
```

After this call though, both `bookmark` and `bookmarkError` are `nil`.

Do I just need to give up on this and create app-scope bookmarks, even though I have a document-based app? That seems inappropriate, but I don't see another workaround.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but something that bit me is the document's fileURL is nil until first saved, so if you haven't set the app-scope entitlement the bookmark creation would fail.

Comment: I ran into that as well. For some reason it worked, even though I definitely didn't set `com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope`. That led me to think I had document-scoped bookmarks working, until I realized that `[self fileURL]` was still nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked about this elsewhere and was told:

> ...we didn't implement support for it because it's complicated and there have been very few requests for it.

So that's that, you can't create this kind of bookmark because it's not implemented. I also filed a bug with Apple but the response just quoted the docs at me (i.e. telling me stuff I already knew and had mentioned in my report) before closing it. So, as of now and probably for the foreseeable future, this is not possible.